# Error Placement of a Form

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to use the following plugin wiht the second form where it places all the error messages inside of its separate div. Only difference is they place it above it and I'm placing mind below. However its still not displaying the messages inside the div for me. Not sure why.

http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/errorcontainer-demo.html

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xtremer360/KHSKm/1/

**Edit**: I updated my code want to show what I have now to how it's not placing the error messages inside of the div I have made for errors when there are errors for the form submission.

Updated Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MtRn6/

Comment: I updated my post you shouldbe going here http://jsfiddle.net/xtremer360/KHSKm/1/ because I forgot to include the validation library and the validation code for that specific form is inside the templates.js file.

Comment: Thanks for editing now I just hope I get someone that knows how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `errorPlacement` to put the error messages where you want them, otherwise it will use the default method of appending them to the input:

```
// container is the element which should hold errors,
// You have already definied it in your demo
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.appendTo(container);
},
```

Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MtRn6/1/

Check the docs for more info: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate